# Add control in TablelayoutPanel row only

Tags: vb.net, tablelayout

I want to add some control in Tablelayout row 2, but control is just added in Split Container instead and not Tablelayout Itself. TableLayout is inside Split Container. How can I add control only to TableLayoutPanel row 2 ? I use row 1 for different purposes, and I need It visible all the time. Here is my code for adding control to TableLayout :

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

 Dim frm = Me 'Form2 that is currently opened too

        If Form1.DataGridView1.Visible = True Then

            Form1.DataGridView1.Visible = False
            frm.TopLevel = False
            Form1.TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(frm, 0, 2)
            frm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
            frm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None
            frm.Show()

        Else 'Do nothing

        End If

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, too fast on posting. Everything is ok, only problem was "frm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized". I changed It to  "frm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill". That solved my issue.